# acts_as_list inside acts_as_tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Let's say we have a `List` model with tree-like structure([acts_as_tree](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree)). Thus, every list can have a parent and/or children.

Basically I want every child of a list to have `position` field defined inside the scope of their parent, how can this be achieved?

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tree
  # acts_as_list scope: :parent <-- desired result
end
```

Or, in another words, How can [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem be used inside the `List` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that scoping `acts_as_list` to non-associative `:parent_id` field (which is required for the `acts_as_tree` gem to work) did the job:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tree
  acts_as_list scope: [:parent_id]
end
```

Comment: You can even do `acts_as_tree order: :position` to make the tree sorted.